# The background image in the span won't show without any text in the span tag

Tags: html, css

The span below will not background image if I remove the inner text xxx

```
<span style='background-image:url("http://gifsoup.com/web/images/soc4.gif")'  style="height: 30px;">
 xxx
</span>
```

*However it works without the xxx in the compatibility mode.*

How do I make it work without any inner text?

Comment: don't mix quote styles in html, you can use single quotes (') in your inline css and maintain double quotes (") for style value. actually don't use inline styles altogether.

Comment: Depending on the context around this element, a `div` may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because spans default to inline elements that don't have a width or height. Change the CSS to:

```
span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:30px;
    background-image:url("http://gifsoup.com/web/images/soc4.gif");
    height:30px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sP7Rd/)**

By changing the display from inline to inline-block you can set the width and height of the span.

Answer (score 1):

the span element is an inline element and as such has no width or height. you must specify in the elements css that it should be displayed as either block or inline-block and then specify the width and height for the image.

```
span{
    display: inline-block;
    background-image:url("http://gifsoup.com/web/images/soc4.gif");
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fYnX5/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a width, and may need to do `display:inline-block`, otherwise the width is 0, so is not visible.